# Why is my `async` function inside a loop not working as it should?

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, asynchronous, async-await

I am trying to run a MySQL DELETE command in a loop, trying to delete multiple items. Below is my AWS Lambda code, written in Node.js.

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const errorCodes = require('source/error-codes');
const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');

const prop = PropertiesReader('properties.properties');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: prop.get('server.host'),
    user: prop.get("server.username"),
    password: prop.get("server.password"),
    port: prop.get("server.port"),
    database: prop.get("server.dbname")
});


exports.deleteSellerPortfolioItemImages = async (event, context, callback) => {

    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    if (event.body == null && event.body == undefined) {
        var response = errorCodes.missing_parameters;
        callback(null, response)
    }
    else {
        let body = JSON.parse(event.body)
        let response="";
        //console.log("body", body);

        for(let i=0;i<body.length;i++)
        {
            
            let idseller_portfolio_item_images = Number(body[i].idseller_portfolio_item_images);   
            console.log(idseller_portfolio_item_images);  

            if (isNaN(idseller_portfolio_item_images)) {
                response = errorCodes.invalid_parameter;
                callback(null, response);
            }
            else {
                // allows for using callbacks as finish/error-handlers
                const sql = "DELETE FROM seller_portfolio_item_images WHERE idseller_portfolio_item_images = ? ";
                await con.execute(sql, [idseller_portfolio_item_images], function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err.toString());

                        if (err.toString().indexOf('cannot be null') >= 0) {
                            response = errorCodes.not_null_parameters;
                            callback(null, response);
                        }
                        response = errorCodes.internal_server_error;
                        callback(null, response);

                    }
                    else {
                        response = {
                            "statusCode": 200,
                            "headers": {
                                "Content-Type": "application/json"
                            },
                            "body": JSON.stringify({ status: 1 }),
                            "isBase64Encoded": false
                        };
                        
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        //If there is no error, this response will be sent back after the for loop
        callback(null, response);
    }
};
```

However this just returns with an empty response, no record has been deleted.

But if I delete the `callback(null, response);` after the `for` loop, the records will be deleted. In that case, an error will be sent back anyway, because there is no `callback`.

I think this is because my code is not waiting for the for loop to complete and just to to the `callback`.

I also tried this as below.

```
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const errorCodes = require('source/error-codes');
const PropertiesReader = require('properties-reader');

const prop = PropertiesReader('properties.properties');

const con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: prop.get('server.host'),
    user: prop.get("server.username"),
    password: prop.get("server.password"),
    port: prop.get("server.port"),
    database: prop.get("server.dbname")
});


exports.deleteSellerPortfolioItemImages =  (event, context, callback) => {

    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    if (event.body == null && event.body == undefined) {
        var response = errorCodes.missing_parameters;
        callback(null, response)
    }
    else {
        let body = JSON.parse(event.body)
        let response="";

        body.forEach(async (element, index)=>{
            let idseller_portfolio_item_images = Number(element.idseller_portfolio_item_images);   
            console.log(idseller_portfolio_item_images);  

            if (isNaN(idseller_portfolio_item_images)) {
                response = errorCodes.invalid_parameter;
                callback(null, response);
            }
            else {
                // allows for using callbacks as finish/error-handlers
                const sql = "DELETE FROM seller_portfolio_item_images WHERE idseller_portfolio_item_images = ? ";
                await con.execute(sql, [idseller_portfolio_item_images], function (err, result) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err.toString());

                        if (err.toString().indexOf('cannot be null') >= 0) {
                            response = errorCodes.not_null_parameters;
                            callback(null, response);
                        }
                        response = errorCodes.internal_server_error;
                        callback(null, response);

                    }
                    else {
                        response = {
                            "statusCode": 200,
                            "headers": {
                                "Content-Type": "application/json"
                            },
                            "body": JSON.stringify({ status: 1 }),
                            "isBase64Encoded": false
                        };
                        
                    }
                });
            }
        })
        callback(null, response);
    }
};
```

This also gave the same result as above.

Why my `async` calls are not working?

Comment: @Ivar: Hi Ivar, I did refer to this question. Thats how I came up with the `for-each` solution. what mistake have i made there?

Comment: @Ivar: You mean adding the `counter` way?

Comment: Typically you'd either receive a callback _or_ return a promise, not both - I'd guess this is true of mysql2. There's no point showing the forEach with an async callback if you already know why that's not going to work.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: My background is Java, Android, Flutter, C++ and Cloud technologies. Not Node.js. Therefor appreciate if you can explain what you really mean. Because for an example in flutter, all I have to do is adding this `async` and `await` and it should work.

Comment: Well you have `await doThing(stuff, (err, result) => { ... })` - have you checked that when your `doThing` receives the callback and calls it back, it _also_ returns a promise you can await? Because generally an API would do one or the other, not both simultaneously.

Answer (score -1):

By default `mysql` module functions are callback based so using `async/await` wont work. See the docs [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql2#using-promise-wrapper) on how to use the promise based functions.

**Mysql Promise Example**

```js
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
const con = mysql.createConnection({...});

(async () => {
  try {
    const [rows, fields] = await connection.execute(...);
    // do something with result
  } catch (err) {
    // handle error
  }
})();
```

Once that is done update your handler function signature like this i.e. ignore the 3rd parameter.

```js
exports.handler =  async function(event, context)
```

A simplified version, skipping code not required for demo of the idea.

```js
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

exports.deleteSellerPortfolioItemImages = async (event, context) => {
    if (event.body) {
        return errorCodes.missing_parameters;
    }
   
    const body = JSON.parse(event.body);
    let images;
    
    try {
      images = validateData(body);
    } catch (err) {
      return errorCodes.invalid_parameter;
    }
    
    const sql = "DELETE FROM seller_portfolio_item_images WHERE idseller_portfolio_item_images = ? ";
    
    const promises = images.map(async (item) => {
      return con.execute(sql, [item]);
    });

    try {
      await Promise.all(promises);
    } catch (err){
      if (err.toString().indexOf('cannot be null') >= 0) {
        return errorCodes.not_null_parameters;
      }
      return errorCodes.internal_server_error;
    }
    
    return {
      'statusCode': 200,
      'headers': {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      'body': {
        status: 1
      },
      'isBase64Encoded': false
    };
};

/**
 *
 */
function validateData (body) {
  // TODO: throw error on invalid data
  // otherwise return an array of idseller_portfolio_item_images
}
```

**Note 1**

The `forEach` function executes the given function for each element in the array (in your case an async function) but it doesnt waiting for the async function result. There are multiple ways to solve this sample code shown

*Options 1*

```js
const promises = body.map(async () => {....});

// using 'all' just for demo use appropriate function in your case
await Promise.all(promises);
```

*Option 2*

```js
const promises = [];

body.forEach(()=>{
  // add the promise promises array
  promises.push(...)
});

// using 'all' just for demo use appropriate function in your case
await Promise.all(promises);
```

**Note 2**

Connecting directly to Mysql DB from an aws lambda function is a bad idea. For-each execution of the lambda function it will create a new connection to db. This puts unnecessary load on the DB server, I recommend that you look into connection pooling. Given its a lambda function doing connection pooling within the function is pretty useless. Checkout [AWS RDS Proxy](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/proxy/)